# Why CipherOutputStream cannot write to ByteArrayOutputStream?

Tags: java, encryption

I am trying to encrypt a string and store the encrypted bytes in primitive array of bytes using `CipherOutputStream` which is backed by `ByteArrayOutputStream` but the size of `ByteArrayOutputStream` object remains zero and it does not conatin any bytes after something is written to `CipherOutputStream` object. Here is the code.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(out, c);
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(cos);
pw.println("Write something");
cos.flush();
out.flush();
System.out.println(out.size());
pw.close();
```

So I tried to make a comparison by changing the `ByteArrayOutputStream` to `FileOutputStream` using the code below. It turned out that the encrypted bytes are written to the target file. Does anyone have any idea why I cannot use `ByteArrayOutputStream` here? Can you suggest a solution as well?

```
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("/path/encrypted.txt");
CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(out, c);
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(cos);
pw.println("Write something");
pw.close();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only difference between these snippets is that in the first case you check the content before closing the stream, whereas in the second case - after closing. So, I guess you need to close the stream before checking.

Comment: Even if I flush, it is still empty. Originally, I don't use `PrintWriter` but write it directly to `CipherOutputStream` which also turn out the same. This is why I am so frustrated.

Comment: @gigadot: Anyway, have you tried to close the stream before checking the content?

Comment: Yes, that works but why? I thought flushing should do the same otherwise why flush method exists? Anyway, thanks.

Comment: @gigadot: Behaviour of `flush()` depends on the nature of the stream. For example, block cipher may need to append some padding to the last block, so it can't write an incomplete block in response to `flush()`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the cipher.

```
  Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
```

Has no padding.
Use

```
 Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
```

instead